# Read specific bytes from a file in PYTHON

Tags: python, file, binary, seek

I want to read specific part of the binary file. I will implement a binary file to "simulate" an array.

For example, assuming that all objects will have the same size (22 bytes hipotetically):

- Inserting an object at index 0 will occupate from 0-22 bytes of the file.
- Inserting an object at index 1 will occupate from 22-44 bytes of the file.

So, when I insert these two objects, i successfully read the second but I get error when trying to read the first one.

Imports

```
import pickle
from sys import getsizeof
```

Inserting first object

```
with open("test2", "wb") as f:
buffer = pickle.dumps(10)
print(getsizeof(buffer))
f.write(buffer)
f.close
```

Console:

> 22

So I insert another number in position 22 using seek()

```
with open("test2", "wb") as f:
buffer = pickle.dumps(20)
f.seek(22,1)
print(getsizeof(buffer))
f.write(buffer)
f.close
```

Console comproving sabe size

> 22

Now Trying to read the second number (number 20)

```
with open("test2", "rb") as f:
f.seek(22,1)
buffer = f.read()
print(getsizeof(buffer))
print(pickle.loads(buffer))
f.close
```

Console log successfuly showing the number and it's size in bytes

> 22
>   20

But now, when trying to read the first one:

```
with open("test2", "rb") as f:
buffer = f.read(22)
print(getsizeof(buffer))
print(pickle.loads(buffer))
f.close
```

Console show wrong requested byte size

> 39

And the error

> Exception has occurred: _pickle.UnpicklingErrorload key, '\x00'.

I don't know if it's relevant, but this is all the file read

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03K\x14.'

Comment: `getsizeof()` does not return the number of bytes read, use `len()`.

Comment: @KlausD.the error remains. len() is returning 5. when i try to read(5) from the beginning of the file shows the error.